# Who was the warrior in Mahabharata who had his eyelids taped to prevent sleeping?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, kurukshetra

I remember reading about a very aged warrior in Mahabharata who had his eyelids taped open to prevent him from sleeping .

He was killed by Arjuna in the Kurukshetra war. Arjuna who was unable to defeat him, under the advise of Krishna cut the tape that held his eyelids open and then finally killed him.

I am unable to recollect his name .
Any help would be appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story in the popular accounts is that of Bhagadatta which appears in the Drona parva chapter XXVIII. It is not present in the translations of the original by Vyasa. However there are many popular accounts of it. For example it is present in the one by [C. Rajagopalachari](https://archive.org/details/mahabharta00craj/page/246/mode/2up)

> Arjuna’s shafts tore the silken napkin that bound up the folds of the aged king’s forehead and he was blinded at once by his own hanging wrinkles. Soon, a sharp crescent-headed shaft came and pierced his chest and Bhagadatta fell like a great tree in a storm, his golden necklace shining like flowers on the uprooted tree.

Answer (score 0):

Gurushavan who had his eyelid pierced to lift them by tying with forehead, as he was very old even to lift his eyelids

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).